# T-SQL convert messed-up date string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a (*temp*) column stored as a `varchar` with fields in the following date format:

`24/07/2005 14:19:54`

When I cast this as a date, it mixes up the day and month - gets them backwards. I need to convert them all to standard date SQL (`YYYY-MM-DD ...`), and I can't figure out the best way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CONVERT` instead of `CAST`.  `CONVERT` allows you to choose a format:

```
convert(datetime,'13/12/2012 10:31:01',103)
```

Formats are listed in the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx); 103 is British (i.e. dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: Great - that totally worked! And thanks for the reference on formats.